# Why is Brian Doyle Murray a coward?

Tags: plot-explanation, reference, arrested-development

In the [*Arrested Development*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0367279/) episode "Missing Kitty" (S01E16) *Tobias*, during his in-prison research for the role of *"Frightened Inmate #2"*, is having difficulties with his new roommate *White Power Bill*. But when he approaches the *Warden* with his fears, he manages to convince *Tobias* of going on:

> **Warden**: But didn't you come here to research the nature of fear? I can't think about a better teacher than White Power Bill, he's like a master's course unto himself.
>   **Tobias**: So you think I'm a coward?
>   **Warden**: There's only one man I thought to call a coward, that's Brian Doyle Murray...No, what I'm calling you...is a television actor.

But **I didn't get the reference to *Brian Doyle Murray*. Who is this and why does the *Warden* call him a coward?** It seems unlikely for the show to just pick any arbitrary name without any relevance to it. Seeing that there is [a famous actor named thus](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0236519/) still doesn't help me to understand his relation to *Arrested Development*. Or maybe it is a reference to some casting related quarrels between the show and the actor (as *Arrested Development* indeed sometimes references incidents related to the show's production itself)?

Comment: I doubt there's a reason. We know James Lipton had access to many actors, so it's funnier and more jarring that he chose to have a bitter tiff, of all people, with a somewhat obscure actor who tends to play affable characters in broad comedies.

Comment: @Walt Hmm, I didn't even know about *James Lipton*'s broader background at all. This gives the *Warden*'s affinity to film-making a whole new angle, it seems.

Comment: Yes, I think some of the jokes with Lipton might fall a little flat without some familiarity with *Inside the Actors Studio*, especially since Tobias is an aspiring actor and Maeby becomes a film executive. Coincidentally, one of the first parodies I saw of Lipton's perceived sycophancy on *ITAS* was on *Mr. Show*, where [Lipton was portrayed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvFV8Oh5VHU) by David Cross (Tobias). The two [made peace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Cross#James_Lipton) on the *AD* set, though.

Comment: "Missing Kitty" seems to be S01E18 rather than S01E16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There is no discernible reason...** [which is why it's funny](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NonSequitur).

A bit of background: The warden is played by [James Lipton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Lipton), founder of the Actors Studio Drama School and host of [Inside the Actors Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside_the_Actors_Studio), where he's been interviewing over 200 stars for more than 20 years. That show also made him somewhat of a cult figure due to his odd affectations and tendency to glorify his guests regardless of their accomplishments, which was the subject of numerous [parodies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xpZ02A9aUVQ) - one, coincidentally, [by his *Arrested Development* co-star David Cross](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvFV8Oh5VHU).

So this makes the line a funny non-sequitor for several reasons:

1. James Lipton is highly unlikely to call *any* actor a coward;
2. We'd expect him to name-drop big stars, not Bill Murray's less known, character actor brother;
3. Calling [Brian Doyle-Murray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Doyle-Murray) that, of all people, is surprising because he's an affable guy who mostly appears in comedies;
4. After a bit of research, there doesn't even seem to be any connection between them, so the joke suggests a mysterious, hitherto unknown bad blood between two amusing figures who aren't really perceived as aggressive.

The joke wouldn't really work (or be less quirky or clever) if he'd mention a well known celebrity or someone who's maligned or known for being cowardly. It's an example of the surreal little moments (and off the wall references and off-beat casting) that made *Arrested Development* so special.